# Neo4j wildcard search on property from java api

Tags: java, neo4j

I am aware how to do that using cypher using [regular expressions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_regular_expression) and I know how to do that if I use the legacy index. But is there another way to do it from the Java API without using cypher and having the overhead of the legacy index? I a bit concerned about the performance with cypher and regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you use the legacy index, not the new index?

Comment: This is want I am asking. I don't want to use legacy index but I don't  know how to do it without cypher.

Comment: What is bad about using CREATE INDEX ON to create an index on the property you're interested in and then use CYPHER to query for your regular expression?